# Unlocking the mouse from full screen game to move it to another screen

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have two screens. mainly I use only one but I want when I'm gaming or something to have skype open on the second screen. this works well, until I want to do something in skype. In both starcraft II and warcraft III the mouse just won't move to the other screen while on the desktop or in non-games the mouse jumps from screen to screen when I move it to the edge.
I there a way to make the mouse still jump from screen to screen when a game is on? or even better have a shortcut that moves the mouse to another screen (like alt-1 will put it on screen 1, alt-2 on screen 2)?

Comment: For years people have been begging for developers to ensure the mouse 'sticks' to the game monitor on multi-monitor systems. Otherwise trying to scroll by pointing to the edge of the screen in a game becomes impossible on the one edge. :)  So +1 for wanting a tool to undo that ("Mouse Un-Jail" perhaps?).

Comment: @techie007, it is game-dependent. Some games don’t have any scrolling or mouse-look like that.

Answer (score 6):

You can always run the game as a borderless window, if the application supports it. However, this can sometimes lead to reduced performance or other issues.

One neat trick I use is the Steam overlay. In fullscreen games that "trap" the mouse to a single monitor, I simply bring up the Steam overlay with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and then I am able to move the cursor to another monitor.

Even if the game isn't available on Steam, you can simply add it to your game library and run it with the Steam overlay enabled.

Comment: Oh, this is genius. Bravo, Fragosaurus! :D

Answer (score 5):

Does the Windows key work in those games? That often works in other fullscreen games, by bringing up the start menu you can break out of the game.

Comment: On starcraft II it does work, but on warcraft III it just minimizes warcraft and is not better than regular alt-tab on single monitor

Answer (score 3):

This is technically impossible unless you run the game in a window.  When a game runs in fullscreen, Windows can't just override that without bringing on some dire comparability issues, the least of which is screen corruption. . .

I suggest you find a way to run your game in a window.

Personally, I like to run my games as "window, borderless." A quick Alt Tab allows me to go to the other monitors yet keep the game up.

Comment: And how do I run it in window, borderless that runs on full screen?

Comment: Most games support it, but the game has to support it :\

Answer (score 0):

some games allow you to go to the other screen but at the games that don't, i just run them in windowed mode but still full screen, a windowed mode that fills up the screen if you know what i mean.. then when you want to change screens, just press start button and you can move your mouse. when you're done then just click on your game window again to continue :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Windows Game Bar to do the same thing as Steam Overlay. When I play Games with controller on pc. Such as Assassin Creed Valhalla I hit the game bar button on the controller to unlock the mouse to move to the second Screen ( yes I'm running game on primary screen in full screen mode).